# Using Streams for iteration in Scala

Tags: scala, stream

[SICP](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/sicp/book/node72.html) says that iterative processes (e.g. Newton method of square root calculation, "pi" calculation, etc.) can be formulated in terms of `Streams`.

Does anybody use `streams` in Scala to model iterations?

Answer (score 17):

Here is one way to produce the stream of approximations of pi:

```
val naturals = Stream.from(0) // 0, 1, 2, ...
val odds = naturals.map(_ * 2 + 1) // 1, 3, 5, ...
val oddInverses = odds.map(1.0d / _) // 1/1, 1/3, 1/5, ...
val alternations = Stream.iterate(1)(-_) // 1, -1, 1, ...
val products = (oddInverses zip alternations)
      .map(ia => ia._1 * ia._2) // 1/1, -1/3, 1/5, ...

// Computes a stream representing the cumulative sum of another one
def sumUp(s : Stream[Double], acc : Double = 0.0d) : Stream[Double] =
  Stream.cons(s.head + acc, sumUp(s.tail, s.head + acc))

val pi = sumUp(products).map(_ * 4.0) // Approximations of pi.
```

Now, say you want the 200th iteration:

```
scala> pi(200)
resN: Double = 3.1465677471829556
```

...or the 300000th:

```
scala> pi(300000)
resN : Double = 3.14159598691202
```

Comment: Only I'd define everything as `def`, so that memory can be garbage collected.

Answer (score 7):

Streams are extremely useful when you are doing a sequence of recursive calculations and a single result depends on previous results, such as calculating pi.  Here's a simpler example, consider the classic recursive algorithm for calculating fibbonacci numbers (1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, ...):

```
def fib(n: Int) : Int = n match {
  case 0 => 1
  case 1 => 2
  case _ => fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2)
}
```

One of the main points of this code is that while very simple, is extremely inefficient.  `fib(100)` almost crashed my computer!  Each recursion branches into two calls and you are essentially calculating the same values many times.

Streams allow you to do dynamic programming in a recursive fashion, where once a value is calculated, it is reused every time it is needed again.  To implement the above using streams:

```
val naturals: Stream[Int] = Stream.cons(0, naturals.map{_ + 1})
val fibs : Stream[Int] = naturals.map{
  case 0 => 1
  case 1 => 2
  case n => fibs(n - 1) + fibs( n - 2)
}
fibs(1) //2
fibs(2) //3
fibs(3) //5
fibs(100) //1445263496
```

Whereas the recursive solution runs in O(2^n) time, the Streams solution runs in O(n^2) time.  Since you only need the last 2 generated members, you can easily optimize this using `Stream.drop` so that the stream size doesn't overflow memory.

Comment: But `Stream` is not random access. So the calls like `fibs(n - 1)` look very inefficient.

Comment: Can you please add code that shows how you can use `drop` to limit memory usage?

Comment: Dan, this is completely wrong. Your solution is O(n^2) because walking down fibs to get to fibs(n) is O(n) on each iteration. Also, the recursive solution is O(2^n), not O(n^2), which is of course, even worse.

Comment: @Douglas, you're correct about the running times, I had edited my answer and screwed up the notation (I originally included the "optimal" solution using tail-recursion which is O(n)), but I don't think that makes my answer "completely wrong."  The streams solution is still an order of magnitude faster than the recursive one.