# Streams vs. tail recursion for iterative processes

Tags: scala, stream, tail-recursion

This is a follow-up to [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8566728/using-streams-for-iteration-in-scala).

I understand that we *can* use `streams` to generate an approximation of 'pi' (and other numbers), n-th fibonacci, etc. However I doubt if `streams` is the *right* approach to do that.

The main drawback (as I see it) is memory consumption: e.g. `stream` will retains all fibonacci numbers for i < n while I need only fibonacci n-th. Of course, I can use `drop` but it makes the solution a bit more complicated. The `tail recursion` looks like a more suitable approach to the tasks like that.

What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

If need to go fast, travel light. That means; avoid allocation of any unneccessary memory. If you need memory, use the fastast collections available. If you know how much memory you need; preallocate. Allocation is the absolute performance killer... for calculation. Your code may not look nice anymore, but it will go fast.

However, if you're working with IO (disk, network) or any user interaction then allocation pales. It's then better to shift priority from code performance to maintainability.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Iterator](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/Iterator.html). It does not retain intermediate values.

Answer (score 1):

If you want n-th fibonacci number and use a stream just as a temporary data structure (if you do not hold references to previously computed elements of stream) then your algorithm would run in constant space. 
Previously computed elements of a Stream (which are not used anymore) are going to be garbage collected. And as they were allocated in the youngest generation and immediately collected, allmost all allocations might be in cache.

Update:

It seems that the current implementation of Stream is not as space-efficient as it may be, mainly because it inherits an implementation of `apply` method from LinearSeqOptimized trait, where it is defined as

```
def apply(n: Int): A = {
   val rest = drop(n)
   if (n < 0 || rest.isEmpty) throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("" + n)
   rest.head
}
```

Reference to a head of a stream is hold here by `this` and prevents the stream from being gc'ed. So combination of `drop` and `head` methods (as in `f.drop(100).head`) may be better for situations where dropping intermediate results is feasible. (thanks to Sebastien Bocq for explaining this stuff on scala-user).

Comment: This is not true, Streams retain all generated elements forever, just like a List would.  The only way to GC some elements of a stream is to get a new stream using `Stream.drop` and let the old Stream get GC'd.

Comment: There was a bug involving constant-space behavior of a Stream, but it is fixed now. https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-692

Comment: It's worth mentioning that `Stream.from(0).foreach(_ => {})` or `def s = Stream.from(0); s.foreach(_ => {})` runs indefinitely, but `val s = Stream.from(0); s.foreach(_ => {})` gets killed with java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space.

Comment: Good point, I was mainly thinking in terms of the second case, where you have a reference to the head and pass it around.

Comment: It seems that using Stream`s `apply` method has deficiencies for that kind of stuff, I'm going to describe it in an updated answer.